# How to configure the SMTP Server on SSRS 2012?

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, ssrs-2012

How to configure the SMTP Server on Report Services/Report Server 2012?

Comment: Hi @MovGP0, I hope that your question was addressed. Can you mark it answered?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Can also be done in a pretty simple way - via Configuration Manager:

[image]

Comment: this is 2016, and question asks for 2012

Comment: @RonaldPaguay, there is pretty much the same process in a configuration of this setting across versions since UI looks the same, beside that authentication. If other than anonymous used, the configuration file to be edited manually in ssrs2012

Answer (score 0):

Go to the folder

```bsh
// Note: adjust the path for your SQL Server version
Set-Location "$Env:Programfiles\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer"
```

Or, for SharePoint

```bsh
// Note: adjust the path for your SQL Server version
Set-Location "$Env:Programfiles\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\Web Server Extensions\15\WebServices\Reporting"
```

Edit the file `rsreportserver.config`; ie. with [VS Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/):

```bsh
code .\rsreportserver.config
```

Find the section `<RSEmailDPConfiguration>`. The individual settings are described here: [rsreportserver.config](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file?view=sql-server-2014#bkmk_generalconfiguration)

**References**

- [Configure a Report Server for E-Mail Delivery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/install/configure-a-report-server-for-e-mail-delivery-ssrs-configuration-manager)
- [RSReportServer Configuration File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/reporting-services/report-server/rsreportserver-config-configuration-file)